# Print Contents of a FILE variable

Tags: c

I am setting a pointer to pointer array of variables that will open the files and count the words.  The issue I am having is how to print the file name in the output.  The counting of the words work (minus a few small accounting for double spaces and such).

The files are entered as command line arguments.  Here is the code:

```
FILE **Files = malloc(sizeof(FILE *) * (count));                            //Array of file pointers

for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{       
    Files[i] = fopen(argv[i + 1], "r");
}
for (i = 0 ; i < count ; i++)
{
    wordCount = countWords(Files[i]);
    printf("File %s: number of words is: %d\n", Files[i], wordCount);       
}
```

I have left out the error checking on if the fopen == NULL to keep it short.  I have tried *Files[i], *(&Files[i]) and a few others in an attempt to print out the contents of the variable.  Is there a way to print out a FILE * varible as a string?

Comment: Use `%p` to and cast the pointer to `void *` to correctly print the pointer value.  If you want the filename that was used to open it, you will need to supply that yourself.

Comment: Creating an array of file handles and then opening a bunch at once is a bad plan, **file handles are a limited resource** and will run out. Instead, in the loop open, read, and close, to keep your file handle count minimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `argv[i + 1]` is the filename, you need to print `argv[i + 1]`. You don't want to print `Files[i]` since it is not a pointer to the filename or anything related in any way to the filename.

You may not be aware of this, but a filename does not uniquely identify a file. A file can have no name at all (for example, if it is removed from the only directory it is in while it's open) or can have more than one name (for example, if it's hard linked into multiple directories). Trying to go from the file to the filename is not simple and something you should only do if you have some specific reason.

Comment: I was afraid of that....  Just didnt want to not ask, just in case there was a better way.

Comment: There might be a better way, but it would take a detailed understanding of your use case to say. What platform? What filesystem? What filename do you want in edge cases? (Do you want the one it was originally opened as? Do you want the file's current name? Do you want all the file's names? And so on.)